# MapProxy + GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

On our Client's environment we setup a MapProxy+GeoServer for maps needed for their application. During the MapProxy seeding process which calls the Layers on GeoServer, the following exception is thrown :

```
[2019-12-31 14:23:20,179] mapproxy.source.wms - WARNING - no image returned from source WMS: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/spin/wms?styles=&format=image%2Fpng&height=224&bbox=-24178.5164836,627512.999999,-4570.27472539,629467.0&transparent=True&layers=Grotere_Steden&service=WMS&width=2248&request=GetMap&srs=EPSG%3A28992&version=1.1.1, response was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException>

      java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/data/spin/Grotere_Steden.shp (No such file or directory)

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/data/spin/Grotere_Steden.shp (No such file or directory)

/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/data/spin/Grotere_Steden.shp (No such file or directory)

</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

The fix needed seems to be on GeoServer side.

The path that needs to be constructed is : "usr/share/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/data/spin/Grotere_Steden.shp" (which was the case earlier. )

But on a new installation in a new machine the path generated is : "/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/data/spin/Grotere_Steden.shp"

I dont understand the change in the construction of the path to the layer file. Please could someone help me with this?

Comment: How did you set up the GeoServer? What is the GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR variable set to?

Comment: I never had to set the value of this variable either in the environment-variables(of the Linux machine) or in the web.xml of the Geoserver application, I Just point the store of the layer to the path I mentioned and GeoServer used to pick it up from there.

Comment: OK, how did you install GeoServer - because it looks like you have borked the data directory path

Comment: I first setup Geoserver in our Linux machine by installing tomcat on it and then deploying Geoserver webapp and then I setup and tested all the layers and configuration via the Geoserver web application. Then I took the Data folder from the Geoserver in tomcat-webapps and prepared an RPM package to deliver it to the client which would setup everything for them in one go.

Comment: That is probably how you broke it then